# Drawing rgb5a1 texture format in metal

Tags: metal, metalkit

I have some textures that I drawn in OpenGL with the unsigned_short_5_5_5_1 and rgba format and i need to draw them in metal. The issue is that metal only supports the bgr5a1 pixel format and i tried to change the data of the textures like this:

```
for (int i = count; --i; rgba++, bgra++)
{
    uint16_t nr = *rgba;
    nr = (((nr >> 1) & 31) << 11) + (nr & 1984) + ((nr >> 11) << 1) + (nr & 1);
    *bgra = nr;
}
```

In the shader I have this code:

```
const half4 colorSample = colorTexture.sample(textureSampler, in.texCoords.xy);
return float4(colorSample);
```

However, the colors are not right and I cannot figure out why.[Metal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNC6b.jpg)
[OpenGL example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnEct.jpg)

Comment: I'm super rusty with OpenGL datatypes, but have you looked at using Accelerate's vImage conversion? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/building_a_basic_conversion_workflow

Comment: So you're using `MTLPixelFormatBGR5A1Unorm`? Have you tried using `MTLPixelFormatA1BGR5Unorm`? I believe it matches OpenGL's unsigned_short_5_5_5_1/rgba layout without any need to bit twiddle (metal's naming conventions for packed 16-bit formats are somewhat confusing).